# which is the statistical test to use between metric groups?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, anova

I'm quite new to Statistics, so I have to write my bachelor thesis till December and my tests were all wrong, so I'd be happy if you could help me.

I want to analyse if there's a connection between the stage of age of the animal and the place where it occurs. The problem is, that the size of the places differ.

So, I have the following data:

```
Adulti/Place1, Subadulti/Place1, Young/Place1, Adulti/Place2, Subadulti/Place2, Young, Place2,... 
0.00357        0                 0.00247       0              0                 0.024
0              0.234             0.0040        0.0032         0                 0
```

Each row shows the number of animals at one age stage per $m^2$ of the place. I'm not sure how I can work with this.

Is an ANOVA the suitable choice? I also heard of the canonical regression, but I'm not sure if this might work.

Comment: Do you just mean that you want to test if the average age is the same in each place? (I guess in your case, perhaps you mean the ratio of adult to subadult in each place.)

Comment: I want to test if animals of an age group differ in the likelihood ofbeing at one place, like Do subadults occur at the same place as adults, also for gender: do males occur at the same places as females

Comment: To me, that sounds like testing the adult/subadult ratio and the male/female ratio. Do you disagree?

Comment: no i agree, but can i simply compare them? or do i have to do some special statistical test (again sorry I´m very new to this :( )

Comment: One other possibility is that you compare if the proportions at each place are 50/50 (or some other expected ratio). It all depends on what you want to do.

Comment: My Nullhypothesis are like this "Males and Females select the same places" is there a statistical test to calculate the ratio?